# when Inserting date from excel file into MySQL DB i have date changing problem

Tags: php, mysql, excel

When I am trying to insert date from excel file into my database the date changes like this:
in excel the date is 29-08-2020 into my database it become like this 03-07-2044
what can i do to solve this problem.
this is PHP code I used

```
    $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($_FILES["excel_file"]["tmp_name"]);  
    foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {   
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();  
        for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)  {  
            $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());  
            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());  
            $mufadala_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue());
            $mark = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue());  
            $secondary_school = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue());  
            $secondary_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue());
            $secondary_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue());  
            $specialization = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue());  
            $is_syrian = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue());  
            $with_mufadala = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue());
            $DbDate = date("YYYY-mm-dd", strtotime($mufadala_date);
            mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8"); 
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_accepted  
                                (Student_Name, Mufadala_Date, Mark, 
                                Secondary_School, Secondary_Type , 
                                Secondary_Date, Specialization , 
                                IsSyrian , WithMufadala)   
                        VALUES ('".$name."', '".$DbDate."', '".$mark."', 
                                '".$secondary_school."', 
                                '".$secondary_type."', '".$secondary_date."', 
                                '".$specialization."', '".$is_syrian."', 
                                '".$with_mufadala."')  ";  
            mysqli_query($connect, $query);   
        }  
    }  
    $output = '';  
    $output .= "تم تحميل الملف بنجاح ";  
    echo $output;  
}
```

Comment: Dates on a MySQL database have to be stored in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` So convert your date to that using the DateTime class for example

Comment: I changed it but still have the same result.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without seeing what you're actually doing, it's hard for us to know where it goes wrong. How is the date stored in MySQL? As date, datetime, varchar? How did you reformat the date?

Comment: *When I am trying to insert date from excel file into my database* Specify in details how do you do it. *I changed it* What you have changed precisely? If you have changed the displaying format in Excel then you have changed nothing.

Comment: In MySQL i save it as date.

Comment: So that was 1 answer to multiple questions/asks. Again, without seeing what you're currently doing (your code), we're left here guessing, which isn't constructive for anyone.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Now I've added the code i used in php.

Comment: `date("YYYY-mm-dd", ...)` - That should be `Y-m-d`. There's a [comprehensive guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for date/time formats in the manual.

Comment: i tried both("YYYY-mm-dd", ...) and Y-m-d but still have the same result.

Comment: Check the answer below that talks about `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. You should use that instead of `date(..., strtotime(...))`. If a date would be `1/12/2020`, PHP won't have a clue if the date should be Dec 1 or Jan 12.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: **How come** your excel date format has changed from `29/8/2020` to `29-08-2020` after answers were provided based on your original information

Comment: It i don't know what exactly but it work. thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that date written in excel file is stored in `$date` with format dd-mm-yyyy.
You have to create your php date time object:

```
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date);
$dataToStoreInDB = $dateObj -> format('Y-m-d');
```

Now you can do your insert query on $dateTOStoreInDB var.

Answer (score 0):

for experience you need in first to replace the "/" with "-" so:

```
$DataStringFormat = str_replace("/","-",$dataBadStringFormat);
```

After do the replace do strtotime to convert data in database format:

```
$DbDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($DataStringFormat);
```

After the strtotime you can save $Dbdate to database without problem

Bye

Comment: They should rather use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead of manually parse the dates. Their current format is a bad one which shouldn't be left to PHP to figure out. If you pass `1-12-2020` to `strtotime()`, PHP has no idea if it's December 1 or January 12. if you use `createFromFormat()` you can explicitly tell PHP how to read the date.